# What would be a word that describe the sound of a sweaty foot walking along a laminated floor

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes  the sound of a sweaty foot walking along a laminated floor. Another instance of this noise being produced would be when you walk along the tile after having just come out of the pool.

Comment: 'Squelch' is perhaps too emphatic. Perhaps 'slap'.

Comment: Squish, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I would say "slap" or "smack".

Comment: This may require consulting comic book sound words.  Perhaps "splat"?

Comment: Squidge or squeak seem strong selections.

Comment: Feels like it should start with 'sl...' or 'sw...' for some reason.

Comment: Since we're already in the realm of onomatopoeia, try making the noise with your mouth and writing that down.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with squish. Slap is too strong, unless one is wearing flip-flop sandals. Squish is the sensation of standing in a muddy lake, swish is related to the air, like a skirt's swishing as a woman walks.  That's too light for the foot.

Answer (score 1):

*The house is dark. A man enters the kitchen, still panting from his brutal workout in the garage. His sweaty feet slosh on the laminated floor as he walks with purpose toward the half-eaten birthday cake.*

I think it works.

*'slap'* sounds good too.
Anything more is too much I think.